# Geb automation - two input field same name

Tags: geb

I appreciate if anyone can help me.
I have a form which separated by

```
*Mailing Address*
*Physical Address*
```

One has ID and one doesn't have. Example: Street
When I use only Mailing address street field and run script - it also insert on the Physical address street field.
I do not know how to get to the Parent DIV to separate Mailing and Physical address Street field. So it can input only in one street address
Any help appreciate.

```
$("input", id: "Street").value("780 woodland ave")
```

**Mailing Address:**

```
></fieldset><fieldset id="fieldset-mailing-list"><legend>Mailing List <a id="mailing-list" name="mailing-list"/></legend><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span12"><div class="control-group"><label for="mailName" class="control-label">In Care of Name</label><div class="controls"><input placeholder="" class="mailName span12" ng-model="Application.contactInformation.mailingAddress" id="mailName" type="text"/></div></div></div ></div><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span6"><div class="control-group"><label for="street" class="control-label">Street</label><div class="controls"><input ng-required="isRequired()" placeholder="Street Number and Name" class="required" ng-model="Application.contactInformation.mailingAddress.street" name="street" id="street" type="text"/><br/><span ng-show="application.street.$error.required" style="color:red">***a required field***<br/></span></div></div></div>
```

**Physical Address:**

`></fieldset><fieldset id="fieldset-physical-mailing-list"><legend>Physical Address  <a id="physical-mailing-list" name="physical-mailing-list"/></legend><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span12"><label class="checkbox"><input name="sameAddress" id="sameAddress" type="checkbox"/>`

**Physical Address same as mailing address.**

```
</label></div></div><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span6"><div class="control-group"><label for="street" class="control-label">Street</label><div class="controls"><input placeholder="Street Number and Name" class="" ng-model="Application.contactInformation.physicalAddress.street" id="street" type="text"/></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Can you post your markup of the page you're driving? It's pretty hard to understand what the problem is and what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to get to the street field and error message. <div class="row-fluid"><div class="span6"><div class="control-group"><label for="street" class="control-label">Street</label><div class="controls"><input ng-required="isRequired()" placeholder="Street Number and Name" class="required" ng-model="formI90Application.applicant.contactInformation.mailingAddress.street" name="street" id="street" type="text"/><br/><span ng-show="application.street.$error.required" style="color:red">***Street is a required field***<br/></span></div></div></div>

Answer (score 2):

To select the street input you can do:

```
$('input', name: 'street')
```

To select the error message you can say:

```
$('input', name: 'street').closest('div').find('span')
```

or:

```
$('input', name: 'street').parent().find('span')
```

or:

```
$('input', name: 'street').nextAll('span')
```